# Error : Shadowed name: 'request' in Firebase cloud function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Here is a Firebase Cloud Function REST Api code.

```
import { request } from "https";

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const firestore = admin.firestore();

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

   response.send("Hello from rocon!");
});
```

Error is :

```
ERROR: /Users/hello/Computer/Development/server/ts_test/functions/src/index.ts[13, 54]: Shadowed name: 'request'
ERROR: /Users/hello/Computer/Development/server/ts_test/functions/src/index.ts[19, 50]: Shadowed name: 'request'
```

Answer (score 4):

You are defining something called `request` with this import:

```
import { request } from "https";
```

Then you are defining another identifier called request in your function:

```
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
```

As it stands now, you won't be able to use the `request` import inside your function because the function can only see the `request` parameter.

You should change the name of one of them so that the `request` in the function doesn't shadow (hide) the `request` from your import.